# Spring MVC annotations configurations

Tags: java, spring-mvc, annotations, pojo

Can someone point me to a link or resource on how to configure the **applicationContext.xml** and **Servlet.xml** files when using annotations. Also i would like to understand what annotations the **POJO's** will be required to have and what definitions are needed in the **applicationContext.xml** and **Servlet.xml** files.

Any assistance even if its code samples will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I learned to set up Spring MVC (configuration files, etc) :

- [Getting Started with Spring MVC](http://blog.springsource.com/2011/01/04/green-beans-getting-started-with-spring-mvc/), from Spring's blog. Really good to begin with.
- [The good old Spring doc](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html), to go beyond the basics.

---

As for Spring layers and annotations, some interesting Stack Overflow posts :

- [What's the difference between @Component, @Repository & @Service annotations in Spring?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6827752/400545)
- [Minimizing controller responsibility](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12569832/minimizing-controller-responsibility)
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/12442657/400545
- [Difference between command, form, business, and entity objects in Spring terms?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11475673/400545)